# jcmdのVM.command_lineオプションが時間経過で使用できなくなる

Tags: java, centos, java8

サーバ内(CentOS)で動いてるJavaVMの起動コマンドを取得する為、jcmdをVM.command_lineオプションを付けて下記のように(1分に1回継続的に)実行しています。

```
jcmd {プロセスID} VM.command_line
```

これが時間経過で下記のエラーが返ってくるようになります。

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131)
```

時間経過はJavaVMで動作しているアプリ内容によってまちまちですが、10日間でエラーが発生するようになる環境もあれば、27日間でエラーが発生するようになる環境もあります。

エラー内容を元に調査すると、以下のページが見つかりました。

[jstack / jmap コマンドを実行した際に "Unable to open socket file" というメッセージが表示されスレッドダンプ/ヒープダンプが生成できません - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/ja/solutions/915983)

上記ページの記述によれば、JavaVMの起動ユーザとは異なるユーザで実行した場合に発生するエラーとなっていますが、今回の事象は時間が経過する前後で実行ユーザは変えておらず、時間経過でエラーが発生する事から原因が特定できておりません。
取得対象のJavaプロセスを再起動すると上記エラーは発生せず、しばらく(10日間ほど)すると再度エラーが発生するようになります。

原因が特定できず、困窮しております。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ぱっと見の回答ですが、Javaのpidファイルが`/tmp`配下などの定期的に削除されるディレクトリーに出力されるようになっていて、それが10日間や27日間で削除されることでこの問題が起きていないですかね？

【回答追記】

このエラーが出るのは、`LinuxVirtualMachine.findSocketFile(int)`がnullを返す時で、このメソッドは/proc/[プロセスID]/cwd/ か /tmp 配下の .java_pid[プロセスID] という名前のファイルの存在をチェックしています。何らかの理由でこのファイルが無いか、権限などの理由で読み込めないはずですね。

```java
// Return the socket file for the given process.
// Checks working directory of process for .java_pid<pid>. If not
// found it looks in temp directory.
private String findSocketFile(int pid) {
    // First check for a .java_pid<pid> file in the working directory
    // of the target process
    String fn = ".java_pid" + pid;
    String path = "/proc/" + pid + "/cwd/" + fn;
    File f = new File(path);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        // Not found, so try temp directory
        f = new File(tmpdir, fn);
        path = f.exists() ? f.getPath() : null;
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: 同環境で「jcmd {プロセスID} PerfCounter.print」も実行しておりそちらは正常に動いておりまして。TAMURA様のおっしゃる可能性もあるかと思い、手動で/tmp配下にあるファイルを削除してみました。しかしながら、「jcmd {プロセスID} PerfCounter.print」「jcmd {プロセスID} VM.command_line」どちらでもエラーが発生し、エラーも表記のものとは異なり、事象を再現する事ができませんでした。tmpwatchの設定を1日で削除するように修正し、事象が再現できないかを検証致します。

Comment: @Sh.nakayama  回答に追記しました。何か思い当たることはありませんか？

Comment: /tmp 配下の .java_pid[プロセスID] のファイルが存在しておりませんでした。こちらがなぜ消えたかについては追って確認致します。

Answer (score 2):

RHELかCentOS環境と想定しての回答です。
`jcmd`等の要求を受け付けるためのソケットファイルが(daily cronで実行される)`tmpwatch`で削除されていると予想します。
(`tmpwatch`は指定のディレクトリにある、一定期間アクセスのないファイルを削除するスクリプトです)

毎日`jcmd`で何かしらアクセスし続けるようcronでスクリプトを記述すると、事象解消すると思います。

＃例えば、GCログのローテートを毎日行う、等です。

Comment: 当環境では1分毎に「jcmd {プロセスID} VM.command_line」のコマンドを実行しており、それが時間経過で突如エラーがするようになります。その為、1分に1度はjcmdでアクセスし続けている状態です。

Comment: コメントの通り、 /tmp 配下の .java_pid[プロセスID] という名前のファイルが削除されておりました。しかしアクセスはし続けているにもかかわらず、削除されている件についてはOSの設定を追って確認致します