# jcmdのVM.command_lineオプションがJavaVM(1.8.0_222)の再起動直後から使用できなくなる

Tags: java, centos, java8, exception

サーバ内(RHEL7/CentOS7ベース)で動いてるJavaVM(1.8.0_222)のアプリ起動コマンドを取得する為、jcmd(jdk1.8.0_66)をVM.command_lineオプションを付けて下記のように(1分に1回継続的に)実行しています。

jcmd {プロセスID} VM.command_line
これがJavaVM(1.8.0_222)のアプリ再起動直後から下記のエラーが返ってくるようになります。

```
java.io.IOException: Connection refused
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.connect(Native Method)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:124)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131)
```

1分に1度「jcmd {プロセスID} PerfCounter.print」も実行しておりそちらは正常に動いておりま。

同一の環境で実行しているサーバは他に100台以上ありますが、当事象が発生指定しているのは1台だけになります。

前回の質問では `/tmp/` ディレクトリ配下のファイルが消失していた事が原因でエラーが発生していましたが、今回は `/tmp/` ディレクトリ配下のファイルが消失している様子はありません。

[jcmdのVM.command_lineオプションが時間経過で使用できなくなる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70855)

原因が特定できず、困窮しております。

Answer (score 0):

接続先のサーバーが落ちているまたは通信で使用しているポートが閉じているのが原因だと
思います。

Comment: だと思って起動中のjavaアプリを確認しましたが、アプリは正常に動作しておりました。javano

Comment: 使用されているポートが開いているのも確認しましたか？FW等もチェックしてみてください

Comment: Javaのアプリを再起動する事で解消しました。また、jcmdも正常に実行できております。次回の事象発生時にポートが開いているか確認したいのですが、どのようなコマンドを実行する事で確認する事が可能かご教示いただけますでしょうか？